# Applying for several jobs at the same company

Tags: job-search, applications

I am finishing up my degree at my university within the next 6 months. I've been starting to apply for all sorts of jobs in which I may remotely be interested. For example, there are a lot of jobs I'm interested in at Google. I always make sure I meet the minimum requirements for these jobs, but oftentimes I'm nowhere near the preferred requirements.

**What positive and negative side effects can I expect from applying for a lot of jobs within the same company?**

<sup>**Side questions:**</sup>

<sup>When the Google form says they think your work shows them enough about you, i.e. a cover letter is not required, do they mean it? Or do they secretly want a cover letter and they're trying to weed out people who don't submit one?</sup>

<sup>How long does a Google job posting typically stay up for?</sup>

Comment: Hi and welcome to WP.SE. I did some editing to your question to put the title more in line with the question asked and moved the google-related questions into a foot note, because they're specific to a certain company. Also, your questions as they were will mainly attract opinion-based answeres instead of the fact-based posts, we're looking for. Please feel free to edit some more, if you think, my changes are inappropriate.

Comment: Your side question is nonsense. If they say "We don't need this", then they don't need it. If you start interpreting statements as not true all communication spirals into a black hole.

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2237/12796 OP, did you saw this?