# Apply twice for two identical but separate job postings at the same company?

Tags: applications

Company X has on its website two job postings. Job posting A is exactly identical to job posting B, EXCEPT that one is in North Carolina and the other is in California. Under each job posting there is a button where I can click to apply and upload my CV and cover letter.

Suppose I am interested in both job postings. My question is: Should I

(i) Apply to both job postings? or 
(ii) Apply to only one and leave a note in my cover letter that I'm also interested in the same job posting at the other geographic location?

Option (i) has the advantage that there'll be less of a risk that I'll be overlooked at either geographic location. But it has the disadvantage that I might confuse/annoy them.

Comment: Definitely apply for both.

Comment: Large companies sometimes have "Standard" descriptions for the positions (ie. every software developer 3 will have the same job posting only varying on location).  The normal advice on applying to multiple positions at the same company would apply here i think.

Comment: @WindRaven: The chosen answer for the question "[Applying for 2 jobs with the same employer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/applying-for-2-jobs-with-the-same-employer)" recommends applying only for 1. Is that also your recommendation?

Comment: @KennyLJ the second highest voted answer also recommends to apply to both.  If the company is large and you have reasons for wanting to move to both locations apply to both.  Just make sure to have a good reason to apply for both other than "I need a job so I spam every thing"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply to both roles. Assuming that the company is fairly large (they have offices on either side of the United States so this is reasonable) your applications will go to two different offices.  Your cover letter should perhaps state your willingness to relocate to the further destination -- other than that they should both be the same.