# Should I send multiple cover letters when applying for different positions at a company?

Tags: cover-letter, applications

A company is offering two positions that I would qualify for. One is more design oriented and requires a portfolio, and I don't think my portfolio is very strong, but I would prefer this position (just an FYI).

Should I submit two different cover letters for the two positions?

Comment: what size is the company? Large companies have different teams and divisions that aren't aware of each others openings prompting 2 separate applys and cover letters.

Comment: Have you had any contact with someone from HR yet on either of the positions?

Comment: It's about 40 people. and @JasonJ I haven't had contact with HR yet.

Comment: Too bad @deannakov I was going to suggest that you just bring it up with them as something you are also interested in.

Comment: I modified the question a bit to focus on the cover letter aspect. The "should I apply to multiple positions" is answered in [Applying for 2 jobs with the same employer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/applying-for-2-jobs-with-the-same-employer)

Answer (score 11):

Don't make it more difficult than it needs to be.

Just reference both positions in the cover letter and highlight there why you think you would be qualified for each one in turn.

I would definitely not send 2 cover letters though.  You're right, that would be rather odd.