# How to apply for multiple positions at the same company?

Tags: applications

There is a huge international company I would like to work for. I applied for a position out of 5 that I found most interesting. They declined me and noted they have decided for a diferent applicant, but would welcome me to use their job agent to find out about future opportunities.

So now as this implys they aren't checking them self possible canidates against other open positions(?) and they are welcoming me to apply in the future, how should I proceed? Simply send an application over their system to any open position I could imagine working in?

Or should I still apply for 1 position at a time, wait a few weeks untill decline and give another try?

---

And in case it would be appropiate to send multiple applications: Should I write diferent covering letters, or keep the content the same, as the reasons I'm reaching out to them and why I would love to work for them aren't very diferent?

Comment: [Should I send multiple cover letters when applying for different positions at a company?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/72303)

Answer (score 2):

Treat them all as separate roles and apply to each one separately.

It's as simple as that.  If you get conflicting interviews or job offers, you'll need to reschedule/negotiate as appropriate.

Comment: So the conclusion is, sending an application for each role I'm interested in?

Comment: That's what I'd do.  Otherwise things get too confusing for both sides.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check what is the company policy for applicants. Some companies do not allow multiple applications, for the sake of reducing load on HR (in big companies each HR can receive hundreds of CV in a day, do not expect them to do your job of matching CV and positions for you).

If the company has no policy forbidding multiple applications, I would still advice you to narrow down your selection in any case.

Multiple applications can convey the message your simply firing in the group or that you are indecisive, and you don't want to be labeled as the serial applicant.

Set some criteria to evaluate the position, rank them and go for the top one.