# How manage applications for two closely-related jobs at one company

Tags: applications

I'm interested in two seperate but very closely related positions that have been posted to the 'jobs' page of a company. One is listed as "[position]" and indicated to be "level 2", the other is listed as "associate [position]" and indicated to be "level 1". The duties listed are largely overlapping, with the more senior position having additional decision-making-type responsibility. My experience meets and exceeds the required and preferred qualifications of the more junior position. I meet most of the qualifications of the more senior position, depending on whether certain parts of my background are considered "related". Based on the information I have now, I would like to be considered for both positions and believe I would be inclined to accept either if offered.

My basic question is, **should I submit an application to both positions or only one?** Additionally:

- If I apply to both, should I mention in each cover letter that I am doing so?
- If I apply to both, should I write a completely separate cover letter for each, or can they be mostly identical?
- If I apply to only one, should I mention in my cover letter that I am interested in the other?
- If I apply to only one, is there a standard way to decide which one?

I should note that applications are submitted through an online form. I do not know whether the positions have the same hiring manager, and I cannot find contact information for a hiring manager for either.

I've seen [this closely related question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/applying-for-2-jobs-with-the-same-employer?rq=1), but I don't think the advice given answers my question because a) that question was about two very different roles, b) it did not address the cover-letter related questions I ask above, and c) the accepted answer was to contact the hiring manager, which I can't do.

Comment: And you do need to call their HR, or if this is a 3rd party recruiter, then call the 3rd party recruiter. Either way, even if there is no phone number on the job posting, I'm quite sure you're more than capable of hunting down the right phone number with a bit of detective work. If on the phone with HR, ask for the name, mailbox info, and department of the hiring manager(s) (if you get this info, use it to send your resume to instead of sending it to HR). If they don't want to give you that info, or if you're dealing with a 3rd party recruiter, then ask them those questions you've just posted.