# Showing Preference between Two Positions for the same Employer

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process, recruitment, applications

I am a freelance writer that gets offered long-term positions for certain companies by working remotely from home. Most of the time, I get asked by the same recruiter or employer if I would like to apply to be a writer or editor or both. I never want to turn down an opportunity, so I apply for both, but I usually prefer to be a writer over an editor. How can I show a preference for being a writer, but still show interest in both positions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying for 2 jobs with the same employer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/applying-for-2-jobs-with-the-same-employer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Companies are usually open to making job roles fit the candidate, when a good candidate appears, rather than being too strict on the simple job description. So you should **be clear & honest about your talents** - you may well be surprised how well this is received by hiring managers.

I would say that **if you love writing then you should absolutely aim for writing rather than editing** as it is easier to perform better when you are happier in a role.

You could also **say that you are comfortable editing perhaps as a secondary role**. It could well be that there will be opportunities that require both skills so this may turn out to be the best of both worlds.